# How to format read-only output value in Adobe LiveCycle ES2?

Tags: livecycle-designer

I need help formatting 'List Annual' and 'Discounted' read only values to be formatted to currency format (example: 123,456,000 OR 12,345).

I have tried the following, but it does not work

```
annual.format.picture.value = "999,999,999"; // Set the field's display picture format.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
annual.format.picture.value = "num{z,zzz,zz9.zz}";
```